# Xslt 1.0 Numeric Variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Usually the programming languages ​​allow you to declare a variable for example:

Dim test as integer <-- Visual Basic

and subsequently allow to increase the value in a for each cycle.

```
for test=0 to 3
    print test
next
```

Can I create a similar structure in XSLT 1.0?

With 'xsl:variable', I declare a variable, but if I want to increase in a for-each as you do?

Comment: XSLT is a functional language, not a procedural or imperative language. Functional languages are different; they do not have mutable state (variables) in the same way. You can achieve the same result, but there is more scope for optimization and less scope for making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest is XSLT 2.0 with

```
<xsl:for-each select="0 to 3">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which processes the sequence of integers `0, 1, 2, 3`.

As you see, it does not use a variable and increments that, as variables are immutable, you simply bind a value to them once.

With XSLT 1.0 you can process nodes or you can write a recursive, named templates where each recursive call passes on an incremented parameter value. Whether you actually need that depends on your requirements, if you are new to the declarative programming of XSLT then it is best that you define your problem by showing a sample of the XML input and the corresponding output you want to create, explaining how the input is mapped to the output.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I am studing the possibilities... there is a way to tag you in my question?

Comment: It is correct:"you can process nodes or you can write a recursive, named templates where each recursive call passes on an incremented parameter value".

Comment: Is that comment meant as question? Yes, you can write templates with parameters and increase or decrease a parameter when calling or applying it recursively. See http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4806.html#d6176e19 for an example. But I would suggest to start with learning how to write templates with match patterns, with positional predicates and how to apply them before dealing with recursion and parameters.